# add class into JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have a class Player and class Enemies, these classes have method paint().
How i can add Player and Enemies into JFrame and get changing pictures from methods paint() of these classes?
result of my code : pictures from method paint() of these classes cover each other.How to avoid it?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RunGame {

    public static void CreateFrame()
    {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Shoot, player!");
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.setSize(1366, 764);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new Player(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.add(new Enemies(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         CreateFrame();  
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm going to *guess* and say that didn't work. Please post `Player` and/or `Enemies`; at least enough for us to see what isn't working.

Comment: *"pictures from method paint() of these classes cover each other.How to avoid it?"* Do you want them overlaid one on top of the other, or beside each other?

Comment: Obscenity removed from your code. Please refrain from posting such things as this site is used by youngsters as well as adults. As for your problem, consider making Player and Enemies **logical** classes, and not GUI component classes, consider separating the logic portion of your program from the GUI portion. Then have your view classes (the GUI) display the position of the logical entities by drawing sprites or something similar in a JPanel's paintComponent method.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you consider

- Making Player and Enemies logical classes, and not GUI component classes as this will allow overlapping.
- Separating the logic portion of your program from the GUI portion, creating at least a Model-View structure, or better a Model-Control-View.
- Have your view classes (the GUI) display the position of the logical entities by drawing image sprites in a JPanel's paintComponent method that is then displayed in the view.